# разница между ::std:: и std:: C++, синтаксис

Tags: c++, синтаксис, операторы, символы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда использовать `std::` а когда `::std::`. Какая разница?

Comment: В большинстве случаев - без разницы. Вот если только кто-то сочинит свое пространство имен, скажем, `namespace my`, в него вложит свое же пространство имен `std`, в него - что-то с именами, дублирующими стандартную библиотеку...  напишет `using namespace my` и начнет вызывать эти вещи - вот тогда придется использовать `::std::`, чтоб отличить пространство имен стандартной библиотеки от этого вложенного `std`. Вероятность встретиться с таким умельцем оценивайте сами... :)